# How to fill up a TableView with database data

Tags: java, sql, javafx, tableview

I've been trying to load a `TableView` with data queried from a database, but can't seem to get it to work.

This is my first attempt at trying to populate a `TableView` with database query items – in case my code seems mungled and far from good.

The FXML was done via JavaFX SceneBuilder.

This is the database query class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class StudentInfo {
    static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";
    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "sa";
    static final String PASS = "";
    
    public static Connection conn = null;
    @FXML
    private TableView<StudentInfo> lovelyStudents;
    
    private ObservableList data;

    // Public static ObservableList<COA> getAllCOA(){
    public void getAllstudentInfo() {
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        String driver = "org.h2.Driver";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String recordQuery = ("SELECT id, KIWI FROM KIWI");
            
            rs = st.executeQuery(recordQuery);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ObservableList row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                
                for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                    System.out.println(row);
                }
                
                data.add(row);
                
            }
            lovelyStudents.setItems(data);
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            // CATCH SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

This is the FXML script generated via JavaFX scene builder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="wakiliproject.SampleController">
  <children>
    <TableView prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
      </columns>
    </TableView>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filling up a Table with database data not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951447/filling-up-a-table-with-database-data-not-working)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the best solution for the filling data to the tableView From the database.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * 
 * @author Narayan
 */

public class DynamicTable extends Application{

    //TABLE VIEW AND DATA
    private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
    private TableView tableview;

    //MAIN EXECUTOR
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //CONNECTION DATABASE
    public void buildData(){
          Connection c ;
          data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          try{
            c = DBConnect.connect();
            //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF CUSTOMER
            String SQL = "SELECT * from CUSTOMer";
            //ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

            /**********************************
             * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
             **********************************/
            for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
                final int j = i;                
                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                    }                    
                });

                tableview.getColumns().addAll(col); 
                System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
            }

            /********************************
             * Data added to ObservableList *
             ********************************/
            while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
                data.add(row);

            }

            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
            tableview.setItems(data);
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
          }
      }


      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //TableView
        tableview = new TableView();
        buildData();

        //Main Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);        

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
      }
}
```

Here is the [Reference](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/comment-page-1/)

Thanks..

Comment: I have connected this code to sqlite database

it works fine but it only add columns when i dont use this code "tableview.setItems(data);"

and when I use this code it loads the columns but does not load rows and gives tons of error

Answer (score 3):

If Database contains different types of data, not only String, then column type assigning is better to make dynamic:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TimeZone;

//Author: Yerbol
//SQL database "sqlbase_schema" contains a Table "sqlbase_table" with 3 columns: "id" (Integer(INT(11))), "name" (String(VARCHAR(45))), "married" (Boolean(TINYINT(1)));

public class Main extends Application {
    private TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //Show window
        buildData();
        Parent root = tableView;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void buildData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection;
        //SQL Database connection params
        String dbHost = "localhost";
        String dbPort = "3306";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPassword = "12345";
        String dbName = "sqlbase_schema";
        String dbTableName = "sqlbase_table";
        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + dbTableName;
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort +"/" + dbName+"?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp&serverTimezone=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        //Connecting to Database
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPassword);

        //Extracting data from Databasee
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ObservableList dbData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataBaseArrayList(resultSet));

        //Giving readable names to columns
        for(int i=0 ; i<resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn<>();
            switch (resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)) {
                case "id":
                    column.setText("ID #");
                    break;
                case "name":
                    column.setText("Person Name");
                    break;
                case "married":
                    column.setText("Marital Status");
                    break;
                default: column.setText(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)); //if column name in SQL Database is not found, then TableView column receive SQL Database current column name (not readable)
                    break;
            }
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1))); //Setting cell property value to correct variable from Person class.
            tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        }

        //Filling up tableView with data
        tableView.setItems(dbData);
    }

    public class Person {

        IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(); //variable names should be exactly as column names in SQL Database Table. In case if you want to use <int> type instead of <IntegerProperty>, then you need to use getter/setter procedures instead of xxxProperty() below
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty married = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public IntegerProperty idProperty() { //name should be exactly like this [IntegerProperty variable name (id) + (Property) = idProperty] (case sensitive)
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public BooleanProperty marriedProperty() {
            return married;
        }

        public Person(int idValue, String nameValue, boolean marriedValue) {
            id.set(idValue);
            name.set(nameValue);
            married.set(marriedValue);
        }

        Person(){}
    }

    //extracting data from ResulSet to ArrayList
    private ArrayList dataBaseArrayList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Person> data =  new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.id.set(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            person.name.set(resultSet.getString("name"));
            person.married.set(resultSet.getBoolean("married"));
            data.add(person);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In this example SQL database "sqlbase_schema" contains a Table "sqlbase_table" with 3 columns: "id" (Integer(INT(11))), "name" (String(VARCHAR(45))), "married (Boolean(TINYINT(1)));

Comment: check these links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808905/javafx-dynamic-tableview-is-not-showing-data-from-the-database) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651641/javafx-mysql-connection-example-please)

Answer (score 1):

```
public TableView queryToTable(String sql) {
    TableView result = new TableView();
    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs)->{
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            result.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        while(rs.next()){
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            data.add(row);
        }
        return null;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks