# Filling up a Table with database data not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx, tableview

I've been trying to load a TableView with data queried from a database, but can't seem to get it to work.

This is my first attempt at trying to fill up a database with database query items, in case my code seems mungled and far from good.

The FXML was done via JavaFx SceneBuilder.

This is the database query class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class StudentInfo {
    static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";
    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "sa";
    static final String PASS = "";

    public static Connection conn = null;

    public List<KIWIDataModel> getAllstudentInfo() {
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        String driver = "org.h2.Driver";

        List ll = new LinkedList();

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String recordQuery = ("SELECT id, KIWI FROM KIWI");

            rs = st.executeQuery(recordQuery);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int Key = rs.getInt(1);

                ObservableList row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                    System.out.println(row);
                }

                KIWIDataModel roww = new KIWIDataModel();
                roww.setFirstName(Key);

                ll.add(row);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            // CATCH SOMETHING
        }
        return ll;
    }
}
```

This is the controller class:

```
import DB.KIWI.Try.KIWIDataModel;
import DB.KIWI.Try.StudentInfo;
import DBQuerry.DynamicTable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<KIWIDataModel> Table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<KIWIDataModel, Integer> colKey;

    @FXML
    public void selectKIWITable() {

        System.out.println("Button Pressed");
        colKey.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<KIWIDataModel, Integer>("Key"));

        Table.getItems().setAll(new StudentInfo().getAllstudentInfo());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

This is the data model class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class KIWIDataModel {

    public SimpleIntegerProperty firstName;

    public int getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(int fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }
}
```

This is the FXML script generated via JavaFx scene builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="wakiliproject.SampleController">
  <children>
    <TableView fx:id="Table" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" fx:id="colKey" />
      </columns>
    </TableView>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Update:** This is the error I get:

```
Button Pressed
    [1]
    [1, First KIWI]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3117)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8600(Scene.java:3055)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3337)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1437)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DB.KIWI.Try.KIWIDataModel.setFirstName(KIWIDataModel.java:14)
        at DB.KIWI.Try.StudentInfo.getAllstudentInfo(StudentInfo.java:49)
        at wakiliproject.SampleController.selectKIWITable(SampleController.java:49)
        ... 40 more
```

Comment: Could you care to share some output of it?

Comment: Hi [Nitesh Verma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1690481/nitesh-verma). Thanks for looking at my question. I guess you mean the error report? I added it in the question as an Update. Hope you can help.

Comment: I am not sure but the cause must be java.security.AccessController as i searched about it. There might be some access control exception where come component in your program might not have the access to some other components like the database. This might be the case why it is not filling the table.

Comment: Can you tell how I can fix this from the error report?

Comment: Check if you have the rights to access the database. This is all i can infer from the error.

Comment: :-) for why reason you re_creating `KIWIDataModel roww = new KIWIDataModel();` inside  `loop while (rs.next()) {`

Comment: In addition to the NPE, you need to use `PropertyValueFactory<KIWIDataModel, Integer>("firstName"))`  [Read here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your null pointer occurs because you never set firstName to anything.  Try:

```
public IntegerProperty firstName = 
    new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
```

Names by the numbers are a strange data model.

Comment: Thanks man. This really looks promising! It seems to work: I get a print-out of the results in the Netbeans console. The table in the GUI changes from "No content in table" after run and draws the raws but no content gets printed in the columns. Thanks again. This is the closest I've been in days to getting it to work. Could you please help me solve this other part? Printing the items into the columns?

Comment: Hey [jewelsea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea). This is what I get printed out:  
Button Pressed
[1]
[1, First KIWI]
[100]
[100, First KIWI]