# What is the use of Callback while adding dynamic data from mysql db in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, callback

While i was searching for adding rows from DB to the table view in javaFX, i came across below code from the following code snippet.

```
Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>()
```

I cannot Understand what it does in this code.
i understood that **setCellValueFactory** is for adding value for the cell
but i cannot understand this series of code from **callback**

```
public class DBFXLesson1 extends Application {

private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
private TableView tableview;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Application.launch(args);

}

//CONNECTION DATABASE
public void buildData() {
    Connection conn;
    conn = new DBConnection().getConnection();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {

        //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF CUSTOMER
        String SQL = "SELECT * from addrbk";
        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        /**
         * ********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY * ********************************
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
        }

        /**
         * ******************************
         * Data added to ObservableList * ******************************
         */
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
            data.add(row);

        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
}

public void start(Stage stage) {

    //TableView
    tableview = new TableView();
    buildData();

    //Main Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

}

My Question is

> what is the purpose of this callback
>   and the flow of the code.
>
> When and Where the rows get inserted to the **table View**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop that contains that `Callback` is just configuring the columns: it's not adding any data. The `Callback` is a function which takes the data from a specific row (in the form of an `ObservableList` in this example) and returns the value from that row in the column being configured: so in this example for column `j` is calls `get(j)` on the `ObservableList` (row data), calls `toString()` on the result, and wraps it in a `SimpleStringProperty`.

The second loop (the `while` loop) actually populates the table with data. It does this (in this example) by creating an `ObservableList` for each row and then adding each `ObservableList` to an `ObservableList<ObservableList>` *(i.e. list of lists) called `data`.  Then at the end it calls `tableView.setItems(data)` to tell the `TableView` to use that as its data list.

This code is not that well-written: it uses lots of raw types and your compiler should be kicking out a whole load of warnings from it.

Typically, you would only use this structure if you had a highly dynamic situation (i.e. the database table had an unknown set of columns in it). Normally, when the database table schema is fixed, you would create a specific model object for each row (instead of using a general `List`) and define properties for it. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651641/javafx-mysql-connection-example-please) uses this more common approach. Even if you have a dynamic case, I would strongly recommend not using raw types for the data structures.

Comment: Thank you so much james. i understood most of the part. I will get completely cleared if you explain how the callback gets the data from `obervablelist` using `cellDataFeatures` i dont have knowledge on what `cellDataFeatures` does here. im a newbie so kindly digest my faults.thanks..

Comment: [`CellDataFeatures`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html) is just a wrapper for the data in a row, which also gives access to the column and the table the data belong to. So `getValue()` just gives a reference to the row data, which is a list in the example.

Comment: then what is a `param`?

Comment: I don't really understand that question. `param` is just the variable name you chose to give to the `CellDataFeatures` passed to the `call(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Put:
return new SimpleStringProperty((String) param.getValue().get(j));
instead of
return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());