# Why the database row data not visible in the JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, javadb

Hello i have an issue i am trying to display data from database into a `TableView` using Java because i couldn't find in `JavaFx` anything like a DataGridView in C#.
I made the following method to fill the table:

```
private void fillTableView() throws SQLException {
        // fill header      
        for (int i = 2; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            tableView.getColumns().addAll(column);
        }       

        // fill rows
        while (resultSet.next()) { // loop through the rows by one
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 2; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) { // loop through the cells of each row    
                // add the value of this cell to the valueToAdd string
                row.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            tableView.getItems().add((row));
            //rows.add(rows);
        }
        //tableView.setItems(rows);
    }
```

The first part works good and the column names are visible however, the rows of data appear empty yet they could be selected, so i can select the first 5 rows in the `TableView` ( I have five rows in my `ResultSet`) but those rows appear empty. I tried to remove this part

```
tableView.getItems().add((row));
```

And instead un-comment the two lines of code below it but still it didn't work.
I tried to make objects initialized with the values from the database then add the objects to the `TableView` rather than adding an `ObservableList` of strings representing the rows as follows but still gave the same result (empty rows)

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            Employee employee = new Employee(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4));
            tableView.getItems().add(employee);
        }
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong please ?

I am using Netbeans 8, Scene builder, Java 8 and JavaDB (aka Apache Derby).

Comment: Try to use `tableView.setItems(row);` instead of `tableView.getItems().add((row));` Remember that the must match the `row/ObservableList` type must be the same as the type of the TableView.

Comment: Here is a link to a query similar to yours: [How to fill up a TableView with database data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941093/how-to-fill-up-a-tableview-with-database-data).

Comment: You could also try searching for "javafx populate tableview from database" - there are issues and examples for reference.

Comment: It is ideal to separate the code that reads from the database and the code that populates/displays the data into he tableview GUI. Try this: (1) Read the resultset data into the `ObservableList` collection _completely_ and after you exit the while loop, try this next (2) `table.setItems(listData);`.

Comment: your columns have no cellValueFactory

Comment: sorifiend: I tried this, it is the commented part in the bottom of the code, but didn't work either
prasad_: i tried this also, in the first trial in the code i loaded my data completely into a result set, then put it into an ObservableList but it gave the same result so i thought i can couple them together but still same issue, but good point
kleopatra: can you further explain more about the cellValueFactory and why would i need to set that in my case, because it's my first time to use TableView