# Adding items into tableview without using an instance of any class

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, dynamic-class-creation

I'm designing a project about cataloging something. In this project user must be able to create his own table as he wish. Therefore I do not have any static class and instance of it.

I'm creating a diaglog pane and I can create textfields for user inputs according to column names of database table dynamically but how can i add those user's inputs into the tableView ?

As I can add any String input into the ListView can I add user String inputs into tableView columns?

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView();
public ObservableList<String> listCatalogNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
listCatalogNames.add("Books");
```

More details with an example;

There is listview that contains all catalog names and according to lisview selection tableview will be created dynamically center of borderpane.

User have books(name, author, page) and movies(name, year, director, genree) catalogs.

Lets say user selected movies and tableView appeared with 4 columns and clicked add button. Diaglog pane created with 4 textfield. I built everything until that point but I cannot add user's input into the tableView because i dont have any static class for Movies or Books etc.

Is there any way to create dynamic class ?

Please give me an idea and help me about that situation.

[here](https://github.com/Se302Team10/Library-Manager) is the **github link of our project**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `String[]` storing the `String`s for every column of a row (or a similar data structure) as item type for the `TableView`. It should be simple enough to create a `String[]` from the inputs and add it to this `TableView`:

```
static TableView<String[]> createTable(String... columnNames) {
    TableView<String[]> table = new TableView<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        TableColumn<String[], String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnNames[i]);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue()[index]));
        table.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Adding a `String[] userInputs` to a `TableView<String[]> table` would be done like this:

```
table.getItems().add(userInputs);
```

---

A similar issue (creating a `TableView` based on the metadata of a `ResultSet`) can be found here: [How to fill up a TableView with database data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941093/how-to-fill-up-a-tableview-with-database-data)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just need to go one more step let say I stored user's input respectively into userInputs[] array how can I add into the tableView?

Comment: Added a little explanation to the answer.

Comment: I owe you a lot, fabian you rescued me from the hell ! Thank you so much ! I'm getting the tableview selected item like this String[] mySelection = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); Finally I did something on my own.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution that comes to my mind is to make use of [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). You can create a super class of both `Book` and `Movie`, let's call it `Item`. Then you can declare your table to contain `Item` and cast to one of the concrete classes when you need to.

Comment: Let me clarify it again the user may creates variety of catalogs and those catalogs may contain variety of attributes(columns) and data types (int,string,double,date). So could you please tell me **how should I implement that super class**? What should I define in it ?

Comment: Do you have a known limited number of possible classes or are the classes created at run time by the user? If it's the latter case you're in for a minefield and I think you should avoid it, but if insist you can do a quick search on how to create classes at runtime.